# VBA Class to persist and restore Excel Application properties

Tags: object-oriented, vba, excel

Very often on Stack Overflow, and even on Code Review, I've seen questions and answers that have code that begins by persisting Excel properties like `DisplayAlerts` and `ScreenUpdating` to public or private variables, and the restores them at the end of the procedure.

```
Public bScreenUpdating As Boolean
Public bEnableEvents   As Boolean
Public xlCalc          As XlCalculation

Public Sub PersistAppSettings()
  bScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
  bEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents
  xlCalc = Application.Calculation
End Sub

Public Sub DisableAppSettings()
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  End With
End Sub

Public Sub RestoreAppSettings()    
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdating
    .EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
    .Calculation = xlCalc
  End With
End Sub
```

That works well enough when the procedure is viewed in isolation, but it mightn't work very well once the call stack gets deeper. That's potentially a lot of private variables to declare and assign, and it can quickly get confusing about when and where properties are set and unset.

Also, there are at least 4 properties that are regularly persisted, but usually only 3 of the 4 are persisted. Namely:

```
Calculation, DisplayAlerts, EnabledEvents and ScreenUpdating
```

Furthermore, if the restore procedure is never called, due to an error or code branching, then the settings are never restored.

The solution? Use a class. I've written a class, and a test harness that shows how it can be used in a stack, and without explicitly restoring the properties. The class exposes properties that allow you to disable certain Excel properties from being restored, and a series of constants allow you to define the default behaviour of the class.

I'd appreciate a review of the class and the test harness. Are there other Excel Properties that could be added?

Class Module: `CExcelProperties`

```
'These constants define the default restoration behaviors for the class
Private Const DEFAULT_RESTORE_CALCULATION = True
Private Const DEFAULT_RESTORE_DISPLAY_ALERTS = True
Private Const DEFAULT_RESTORE_ENABLE_EVENTS = True
Private Const DEFAULT_RESTORE_SCREEN_UPDATING = True

'Set this to true to ensure a persisted state is restored, even if the consumer forgets to restore
Private Const RESTORE_ON_TERMINATE = True

'Private members stored in a Type
Private this As TMembers

Private Type TMembers
  Calculation As XlCalculationState
  DisplayAlerts As Boolean
  EnableEvents As Boolean
  ScreenUpdating As Boolean
  RestoreCA As Boolean
  RestoreDA As Boolean
  RestoreEE As Boolean
  RestoreSU As Boolean
  IsPersisted As Boolean
  IsRestored As Boolean
End Type

'Set the default restoration behaviours on intialize
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  this.RestoreCA = DEFAULT_RESTORE_CALCULATION
  this.RestoreDA = DEFAULT_RESTORE_DISPLAY_ALERTS
  this.RestoreEE = DEFAULT_RESTORE_ENABLE_EVENTS
  this.RestoreSU = DEFAULT_RESTORE_SCREEN_UPDATING
End Sub

'By default, restore the settings if we didn't do it explicitly
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  If this.IsPersisted And Not this.IsRestored And RESTORE_ON_TERMINATE Then
    Me.Restore
  End If
End Sub

Public Property Get RestoreCalculation() As Boolean
  RestoreCalculation = this.RestoreCA
End Property

Public Property Let RestoreCalculation(Value As Boolean)
  this.RestoreCA = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RestoreDisplayAlerts() As Boolean
  RestoreDisplayAlerts = this.RestoreDA
End Property

Public Property Let RestoreDisplayAlerts(Value As Boolean)
  this.RestoreDA = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RestoreEnableEvents() As Boolean
  RestoreEnableEvents = this.RestoreEE
End Property

Public Property Let RestoreEnableEvents(Value As Boolean)
  this.RestoreEE = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RestoreScreenUpdating() As Boolean
  RestoreScreenUpdating = this.RestoreSU
End Property

Public Property Let RestoreScreenUpdating(Value As Boolean)
  this.RestoreSU = Value
End Property

Public Sub Save()
  If Not this.IsPersisted Then
    'Save all of the settings
    With Application
      this.Calculation = .Calculation
      this.DisplayAlerts = .DisplayAlerts
      this.EnableEvents = .EnableEvents
      this.ScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
    End With
    this.IsPersisted = True
  Else
    Err.Raise -1000, "CExcelProperties", "Properties have already been persisted."
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Restore()
  'Only restore the settings that we want restored
  '(which by default is all of them)
  With Application
    If this.RestoreCA Then
      .Calculation = this.Calculation
    End If
    If this.RestoreDA Then
      .DisplayAlerts = this.DisplayAlerts
    End If
    If this.RestoreEE Then
      .EnableEvents = this.EnableEvents
    End If
    If this.RestoreSU Then
      .ScreenUpdating = this.ScreenUpdating
    End If
  End With
  this.IsRestored = True
End Sub
```

Standard Module:

```
Sub TestHarness()

  Dim cProps As CExcelProperties

  Set cProps = New CExcelProperties

  'Save the current properties
  cProps.Save

  'Adjust the Application properties
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  'Run something that further adjusts the Application properties
  Call SubProcess

  cProps.Restore

End Sub

Sub SubProcess()

  Dim cProps As CExcelProperties

  Set cProps = New CExcelProperties

  'Save the current properties
  cProps.Save

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  'Limit the restoration to exclude calculation
  cProps.RestoreCalculation = False

  'Deliberately don't restore, and the terminate event should restore the properties for us

End Sub
```

Comment: I love this. Definitely going to have to make me one of these ^^

Comment: Might consider `Application.Visible` as well.  I change that one from time to time and would benefit from it resetting correctly if the code fails.

Comment: I would add this property too to have a better visual for dashboards or an interactive sheet with charts or shapes etc: `Application.DisplayFormulaBar`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like the idea very much - encapsulating this concern in its own class is very OOP and certainly helps writing cleaner VBA.

I like that you're wrapping all fields in a private type, leaving only `this` as a private field, which makes implementing (and more importantly, *reading*!) the properties a pleasure. I would have made the private type's member names match the properties identically though: `RestoreCA` and the other abbreviated members feel a bit sloppy, there's not really a reason to not spell them out completely. Doing so would have been perfectly consistent.

I'm not sure why `RESTORE_ON_TERMINATE` is a constant rather than a configurable property though; code shouldn't need to change, especially not for changing a *constant* value. Rename it to `DEFAULT_RESTORE_ON_TERMINATE` and add the corresponding members, and you're never going to need to change it.

I think I would nest the condition in `Class_Terminate`, to check for `this.RestoreOnTerminate` and skip the other checks entirely when it's `false`.

I don't think any of the comments provide any value - your code is clear and readable, and speaks for itself already; the comments are somewhat redundant, I'd remove them.

The name `Save` isn't consistent with the terminology you're using, I'd rename it to `Persist`... but either is somewhat confusing, since you're not physically *persisting* anything, merely *remembering* values for the lifetime of the object - but `Remember` would be even more awkward, so you're forgiven ;-)

The `With` blocks are fine, but I wouldn't have them... but this might only be because I dislike additional nesting levels more than repetitive/explicit calls to the same object. Or it could be my C# eyes being used to such explicit calls. Or it could be just me not liking the VB `With` keyword at all - in that case don't mind me, your code is fine.

I don't like the hard-coded -1000 error number there. A smart little ducky once showed me a neat little trick that stuck with me:

```
Public Enum ExcelPropertiesError
    Error_AlreadyInitialized = vbObjectError + 42
End Enum
```

And now you can do this:

```
Err.Raise Error_AlreadyInitialized '...
```

And the client code that's handling it can use the enum instead of hard-coding error numbers everywhere, and if you have more errors to raise, you just add an enum member and VBA automatically makes it `vbObjectError + 43` :-)

Your tests are insufficient. Get [Rubberduck](http://rubberduck-vba.com) and write actual *unit tests* that cover all execution paths: you want one test to cover one thing, or rather, you want each test to have *one reason to fail* - and more importantly you want your tests to fail when something changes in the class under test, that changes the behavior that the test is documenting.

For example, you'll want a test that fails when `Error_AlreadyInitialized` isn't raised when you call `Save` twice.

You'll want a test for each property you're persisting, that fails when the getter doesn't return the value that was persisted; you'll want a test for each getter again, that fails when it doesn't return the expected value after it was saved and then modified.

Also, you'll want a test that covers this nasty gotcha:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim props As New CExcelProperties
    props.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'does it restore?
End Sub
```

You'll also want to test what happens when more than once instance is alive at different depths in the call stack; you might want to consider making the class have a `PredeclaredId` and living inside a separate project than the client code that uses it, so that is can't be instantiated and every call is made on the same, default instance - how would the `Terminate` handler deal with that?

---

Nitpicks:

- `Call` is obsolete, forget it even exists. Use the modern *implicit call* syntax for calling functions and procedures instead:

  ```
  SubProcess 'instead of Call SubProcess
  ```
- The `value` parameter of each getter is implicitly passed `ByRef`, and should be passed `ByVal`. That's something Rubberduck lets you fix with a single click.

Comment: The constants were designed so that a developer could alter the default behaviors without having to edit any code. It's logical, for my workload, to save and restore the calculation property, but it mightn't be a property that you want to change, or want to have to turn off every time, so the constants were a way of making the class adaptable to a developer's preferred default behavior. I like your point about the Restore on Terminate being exposed as a property. I actually added the Terminate event in the CR textbox, so I wasn't in IDE/OOP mentality when I added it.

Comment: Likewise the members of the *this* type, and their usage, were typed in the CR textbox, so abbreviating them was easier than typing them in full without Intellisense. So yes, the Type members should match the property names.

Comment: I've used your error numbering approach in my own implementation, but I wanted to keep the example focused on the persistence. Adding in a bunch of error handling *is* necessary, but I didn't want it to clutter the code.

Comment: I believe your nasty Initialize gotcha is the issue I added to RubberDuck earlier!

Comment: Ideally you put up your *actual* code for review, so as to avoid "yes but *my real code does X*" replies ;-) ...and yeah, that gotcha is something Rubberduck should warn about; I'm just saying, tests should *document a class' behavior/specs*, so when all tests pass you *know* it's working as intended, and you know what the intent is just by looking at test names, not by looking at the class' implementation.

Comment: FGITW Nice review.

Comment: I would suggest using "Back up" instead of "Save" as the appropriate method name. I think that is clear and useful.