# Transforming and quantizing some numbers in a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two functions which am currently running separately and would like them to run at once.

The `cartMaxCalc` calculates and populates column `O`, then `minfinder` function uses the calculated values of column `O` with values of column `M` to finally set the values of column `O`.

I am a novice on VBA and would like some pointers on how to refactor this and make it clean.

[image]

```
'Name:         Optimum
'Description :
'
'
'
'
'
'Date        :
'Team        :
'Purpose     :
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim i As Long
'Loop to get cells with values for calculations
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To FinalRow
'Output results to cells and columns
Cells(i, 15).Value = cartMaxCalc(i)
'Write Column Headers
Range("O1").Value = "CART_MAX"

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function cartMaxCalc(i As Long)

Dim quadrantStyle As Variant
Dim cartMx As Long
Dim cartMax1 As Long
Dim stacking As Long
Dim devLoc As Variant
Dim contQty
Set contQty = Cells(i, 6)
Dim contTypeRange
Set contTypeRange = Cells(i, 5)


 ' determine category by first 2 digits of cell
    Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 11).Value, 2))
        Case "E"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "B", "J3", "B0"
                    cartMx = 4 * contQty
                Case "C", "C0", "J2", "B2"
                    cartMx = 8 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1", "j4"
                    cartMx = 16 * contQty
                Case "D1"
                    cartMx = 24 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select

        Case "G", "P"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "B", "J3", "B0", "D1"
                    'do nothing
                Case "C", "C0", "J2"
                    cartMx = 6 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1"
                    cartMx = 12 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select

        Case "T", "F", "R", "L"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "B", "J3", "B0"
                    cartMx = 2 * contQty
                Case "C", "C0", "J2", "B2"
                    cartMx = 4 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1"
                    cartMx = 8 * contQty
                Case "D1"
                    cartMx = 12 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select
        Case Else
            cartMx = contQty
    End Select

        cartMaxCalc = cartMx

 End Function
Sub minFinder()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim minRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim cartmax

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") 'will change to activeSheet

With ws
 Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 13), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
 Set minRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 15), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp))
End With
For Each cel In rng
 'check column M to find any values that repeat more than twice, find the minimum of the their values in column O
 cartmax = Evaluate("=MIN(IF(" & cel.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng.Address(0, 0) _
 & "," & minRng.Address(0, 0) & "))")
' determine the final value by which range they fall in.
Select Case cartmax
 Case 0 To 29
  cartmax = 13
 Case 30 To 59
  cartmax = 30
 Case 60 To 119
  cartmax = 60
 Case 120 To 179
  cartmax = 120
 Case 180 To 239
  cartmax = 180
 Case 240 To 299
  cartmax = 240
 Case 300 To 359
  cartmax = 300
 Case 360 To 419
  cartmax = 360
 Case 420 To 479
  cartmax = 420
 Case 480 To 539
  cartmax = 480
 Case 540 To 599
  cartmax = 540
 Case 600 To 659
  cartmax = 600
 Case 660 To 719
  cartmax = 660
 Case 720 To 779
  cartmax = 720
 Case 780 To 839
  cartmax = 780
 Case 840 To 899
  cartmax = 840
 Case 900 To 959
  cartmax = 900
 Case Is >= 960
  cartmax = 960
 End Select
cel.Offset(, 2).Value = cartmax
Next cel


End Sub
```

Comment: By "At once" do you mean "In one subroutine, one after the other?" Because if you actually want 2 inter-dependent subroutines to run in paralell then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I meant to either have two functions to be called in the main Sub or just call one cartMaxCalc() in the Main sub and have cartMaxCalc() call minFinder()

Comment: Then why not just call minfinder at the end of your main sub?

Comment: I can do that, just wanted to learn and bounce the code with experienced vba programmers to get a review/constructive inputs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your code is actually doing? I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to calculate, and failing (Hint: Not a good sign). Could you add a short description? A screenshot of your worksheet would also be really useful.

Comment: @Zak, the code actually works as intended

Comment: Am calculating Cart_Max (Last Column in the screenshot). Cartmaxcalc is using multiplying cont_QTY column by a value assigned to Cont_Typ to get the initial value of Cart_MAx column. If values in column UNload appear more than once, then minFinder evaluates the minimum value of the set then overwrites column Cart_Max with the final value. the screen shot is actually a result of the running the code. hope this helps clarify

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the line `cartmax = Evaluate("=MIN(IF.......` in your `minFinder` sub. It looks to me that it compares the `cel` value in `rng` to the first value of the `rng` and then if the are the same it uses the first value of the `minRng`.

Answer (score 1):

Just Evaluating the Script, Not the Application of it.

**Indentation**

I see you have used some indentation in your `Public Function cartMaxCalc(i As Long)`, and pretty good at that,  but not the rest of the Subs or Functions. Always make sure that you indent your lines referring to `With`, `For`, etc statements.

---

**Variable Naming**

This is the first place anyone will comment/review (as I am doing). It’s always good to give descriptive names. I know it’s so easy and quick to use `For i / j / k to …..` but really just adding a few extra characters never hurt anyone, you also have some good descriptive names `cartMaxCalc` so you can do it, just need to keep doing it. It will also help the next person in 5 years time.

---

**Redo Example**

If I had to redo your `Main` Sub, and I am but no means the best.

```
Sub PopulatingColumnOWithCartMaxData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write Column Header
    Range("O1").Value = "CART_MAX"

    Dim FinalRow As Integer
    Dim RowReference As Integer

    'Loop to get cells with values for calculations
    FinalRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowReference = 2 To FinalRow

        'Output results to cells and columns
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowReference, 15).Value = cartMaxCalc(RowReference)

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In the above notice the following:

> Descriptive `Sub` Title
>
> Moving the Column Title Insertion to above the `For` Loop, as it has nothing to do with the Loop.
>
> Adding the `WorkBook` and `WorkSheet` reference to the the various places where `Cells(….)` is used. If there if another WorkBook was active or another sheet then you could get wrong data.
>
> Using `RowReference` instead of `i`. Once a variables has been `Dim`ed then its in the database so then just CTRL + SPACE and start typing and it will appear quickly.
>
> Spacing between *ideas* in your `Sub`. Try and have an empty line between parts of your code which then sort of separates the *ideas* in your `Sub`.
>
> I also used `Integer` instead of `Long`, `Integer` just doesn’t have a decimal place. More of a preference really.

Also [ThunderFrame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/94097/thunderframe) has some great data [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/vba-class-to-persist-and-restore-excel-application-properties) which provides the automatic restoration of the `ScreenUpdating` and others. If your script bombs out and your have not restored the updating then the user will not know what to do.

---

**In the `Public Function cartMaxCalc(i As Long)`**

There are a few `Variables` which haves been `Dim` but not used.

When you assigning Values to `contQty` and `contQty` you didn’t set the Data Type (`Range`, `String`, `Long`). Also, only if you want to use a `Range` must you use `Set`. I would have done the following:

```
Dim contQty As Double ‘Double has decimal places
contQty = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value
Dim contTypeRange As String ' String because it will have Alpha Numerical data
contTypeRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
```

Also change the `i` to something like `CurrentRowReference` to be more descriptive. Once in the Function is possible, at first glance, to not see what the `i` is referring to. Always remember your WorkBook and WorkSheet Reference. If you using the WorkSheet Reference more than twice then I would recommend Setting it up as a variable.

---

**In `Sub minFinder()`**

`Sub` Title is not bad, can just be ..................more descriptive. Dont worry, it has taken me a while to come out of my Non-descriptive ways.

Remember your `WorkBook` and `WorkSheet` reference when setting a `Range`.

Fairly good use of indents.

You did not set the Data Type for `cartmax`.

Also I am struggling to see what you trying to do with the line:

```
cartmax = Evaluate("=MIN(IF( " & cel.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "," & minRng.Address(0, 0) & "))")
```

Firstly, if you want to use the worksheet functions, just use `WorksheetFunction`. So for your case where you want to use `Min` then use `WorksheetFunction.Min`.

Comment: Nice answer, but `Integer` is a signed 16-bit value type, which gives it a maximum value of 32,767. `Long` is 32-bit, which gives it a maximum value that is orders of magnitude greater than `Integer`; anything that represents an Excel row number should be a `Long`, to avoid overflow errors... it's not *quite* a matter of *preference* ;-)

Comment: Thanks Jean-Pierre, I cleaned-up the code and will be posting it up here soon...

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have some input here. First - your variables. I can't tell what they are for. I'd use

Main

```
    Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
    Set myWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim cartWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set cartWorksheet = myWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    FinalRow = carworksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    currentColumn = 15 'Column O

    cartWorksheet.Cells(1, currentColumn) = "CART_MAX"

    For currentRow = 2 To FinalRow
        cartWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) = cartMaxCalc(currentRow)
```

Now we know with what and where we're working

Now we move to `cartMaxCalc` and I have a couple of questions:

- Why is `devLoc` defined, I don't see it used anywhere
- Why is your `Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 11).Value, 2))` asking for 2 characters when all of your cases have 1 character? I thought maybe they have a null character or something. I'd do it like this -

  ```
  Dim myCaseString As String
  'Why are you taking left(string,2) when all your cases have 1 character?
  myCaseString = Trim(UCase(Left(Cells(myRow, myColumn), 2)))
  ```
- What's the difference between `cartMx` and `cartMax1`? Why have the "1" if they don't have the same name (not that that's good practice)? Why have such close names? Oh wait, `cartMax1` is never used, so we can get rid of it! Now we just say `cartMx` is `cartMaximum`.
- Your function takes an argument, but you don't tell it *how* to take it. It will assume byRef so instead - `Public Function cartMaxCalc(ByVal myRow As Long)`
- You never use `stacking` either
- Or `quadrantStyle`

So now the beginning of this function looks like this

```
Public Function cartMaxCalc(ByVal myRow As Long)
    Dim cartMaximum As Long
    Dim myColumn As Long
    myColumn = 11
    Dim myCaseString As String
    'Why are you taking left(string,2) when all your cases have 1 character?
    myCaseString = Trim(UCase(Left(Cells(myRow, myColumn), 2)))

    Dim contQuantity As Range
    Set contQty = Cells(myRow, 6)

    Dim contTypeRange As Range
    Set contTypeRange = Cells(myRow, 5)
```

Now we get to your `CASE` selection. As I mentioned, the first level cases all have one character, so why are you getting 2?

The second level of `CASE` is

```
select case [range]
    Case "B", "J3", "B0"
    Case "c", "C0, "J2", "B2"
    etc
```

What are you selecting the range for? And how do the cases apply to it? That goes for all of the cases. Otherwise, the structure of the cases is fine and we return the `cartMaximum` as the value of the function and pass it back to main.

In terms of calling these two together, let's examine `minFinder`

What is `cartmax` doing?

```
cartmax = Evaluate("=MIN(IF(" & cel.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng.Address(0, 0) _
 & "," & minRng.Address(0, 0) & "))")
```

Let my decipher this - if a cell in M column repeats, give the lower value in the respective O column, right? That means we have to do it all *after* our first loop because we need all of column O. Now I can't put forth a better way to do that *if* but I would change `minFinder` to

```
Public Sub minimumCart(byVal myWorksheet As Worksheet)
    Dim columnOLastRow As Long
    columnOLastRow = myWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim columnMLastRow As Long
    columnMLastRow = myWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim myTestColumnO As Range
    Set myTestColumnO = myWorksheet.Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(columnOLastRow, 15))
    Dim myTestColumnM As Range
    Set myTestColumnM = myWorksheet.Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(columnMLastRow, 13))

    Dim myCurrentTestCell As Range

    Dim cartmax
```

So at the end, main looks like this -

```
Sub Main()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
    Set myWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim cartWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set cartWorksheet = myWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    FinalRow = cartWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    currentColumn = 15 'Column O

    cartWorksheet.Cells(1, currentColumn) = "CART_MAX"

    For currentRow = 2 To FinalRow
        cartWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) = cartMaxCalc(currentRow)
    Next

    minFinder (cartWorksheet)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

One way to refactor it might be that you call for all of each duplicate in column M and then call `cartMaxCalc` for all of them, returning the minimum.

---

Actually, one way to do this (simplified obviously) would be to use a dictionary to compare values like this -

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If Not dict.exists(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                dict.Add Cells(i, 1).Value, Cells(i, 2).Value
            ElseIf Cells(i, 2).Value < dict(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                dict(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next
```

You'd have to calculate `O` each time, but `M` would have the lowest value when you went back through and reset `O`.