# Code to analyse text get stuck if too much data

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel, time-limit-exceeded

I've made the following VBA script to analyse text recurrence in a huge batch of descriptions.

For a **small part** of the batch the **code run smoothly**, but when I include **everything** it tends to loose control, get stuck and **both Excel and VBE freeze**.

What I did to avoid this (at least most of the times), is to include temporisation (`DoEvents`) and use the Immediate Window to show that the code is still "alive" :

```
If Int(i / 1000) = i / 1000 Then
    Debug.Print i
Else
    If Int(i / 100) = i / 100 Then
        DoEvents
    Else
    End If
End If
```

I guess there are better ways to handle that kind of behavior in VBA, but I don't know.

Here is the full code, that is probably improvable :

```
Sub test_usedW()
Dim A()
A = get_most_used_words_array(An_Array, 1, True)
End Sub

Function get_most_used_words_array(ByVal ArrayToAnalyse As Variant, Optional ByVal ColumnToAnalyse As Integer = 1, Optional OutputToNewSheet As Boolean = False) As Variant
Dim A() As String, _
    wb As Workbook, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    Dic As Scripting.Dictionary, _
    DicItm As Variant, _
    NbMaxWords As Integer, _
    TpStr As String, _
    Results() As Variant, _
    DicItm2 As Object, _
    R(), _
    iA As Long, _
    i As Long, _
    j As Long, _
    k As Long, _
    c As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = TextCompare

NbMaxWords = 5


'--1--Balayage du tableau
For iA = LBound(ArrayToAnalyse, 1) To UBound(ArrayToAnalyse, 1)
    If ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse) <> vbNullString Then
        '--2--Uniformisation des descriptions pour plus de "conformité"
        ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse) = CleanStr(ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse))
        A = Split(ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse), " ")
        DoEvents
        '--1--Ajout mots simples
        For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
            TpStr = CleanStr(A(i))
            If Len(TpStr) > 3 Then
                If Not Dic.exists(TpStr) Then
                    Dic.Add TpStr, TpStr
                Else
                    DoEvents
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next i
        '--1--Ajout expressions (plusieurs mots)
        If NbMaxWords < 10 Then
            For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
                For k = 2 To NbMaxWords
                    j = 0
                    TpStr = vbNullString
                    Do While j <= k And i + j <= UBound(A)
                        TpStr = TpStr & " " & CleanStr(A(i + j))
                        j = j + 1
                    Loop

                    TpStr = CleanStr(TpStr)
                    If Len(TpStr) > 3 Then
                        If Not Dic.exists(TpStr) Then
                            Dic.Add TpStr, TpStr
                        Else
                            DoEvents
                        End If
                    Else
                        DoEvents
                    End If
                Next k
            Next i
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next iA


'Results = Application.Transpose(Dic.Items)   
ReDim Results(Dic.Count - 1)   
For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
    Results(i) = Dic.Items(i)
    If Int(i / 1000) = i / 1000 Then
        Debug.Print i
    Else
        If Int(i / 100) = i / 100 Then
            DoEvents
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next i

ReDim R(1 To UBound(Results), 3)
Debug.Print "UBound(Results) : " & UBound(Results)

For i = 1 To UBound(Results)
    R(i, 0) = Results(i)    ', 1)
    R(i, 2) = Len(R(i, 0))
    For iA = LBound(ArrayToAnalyse, 1) To UBound(ArrayToAnalyse, 1)
        If ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse) <> vbNullString Then
            'Affinage du compatge? Exclusif? instr(" " & search & " ")?
            If InStr(1, ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse), R(i, 0)) Then R(i, 1) = R(i, 1) + 1
            If InStr(1, ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse), " " & R(i, 0) & " ") Then R(i, 3) = R(i, 3) + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next iA
    If Int(i / 1000) = i / 1000 Then
        Debug.Print i
    Else
        If Int(i / 100) = i / 100 Then
            DoEvents
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next i

DoEvents
If OutputToNewSheet Then
    Set wS = wb.Worksheets.Add
    wS.Activate
    'ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(R, 1), UBound(R, 2)).Value = R

    For i = LBound(R, 1) To UBound(R, 1)
        For j = LBound(R, 2) To UBound(R, 2)
            If InStr(1, R(i, j), "=") Then
                wS.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = "'" & R(i, j)
            Else
                wS.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = R(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    DoEvents
Else
End If

DoEvents
get_most_used_words_array = R
End Function
```

And the functions to "simplify" text :

```
Function CleanStr(ByVal TheString As String)
    Dim SpA() As String
    Dim SpB() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Const AccChars = "–| - | -|- |-| / | /|/ | . | .|. | , | ,|, | ) | )|) | ( | (|( |=|    |   |  "
    Const RegChars = " | | | | |/|/|/|.|.|.|,|,|,|)|)|)|(|(|(|'=| | | "
    SpA = Split(AccChars, "|")
    SpB = Split(RegChars, "|")

    For i = LBound(SpA) To UBound(SpA)
        TheString = Replace(TheString, SpA(i), SpB(i))
    Next i

    CleanStr = StripAccent(Trim(Trim(TheString)))
End Function

Function StripAccent(ByVal TheString As String)
    Dim A As String * 1
    Dim B As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer
    Const AccChars = "àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ"
    Const RegChars = "aaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyySZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUY"

    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        TheString = Replace(TheString, A, B)
    Next i

    StripAccent = TheString
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

**Simple speed-enhancements**

The 3 lowest hanging fruit in the VBA performance garden are

- `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
- `Application.EnableEvents = False`
- `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Personally, I have the following standard Methods for dealing with those:

```
Option Explicit

Public varScreenUpdating As Boolean
Public varEnableEvents As Boolean
Public varCalculation As XlCalculation

Public Sub StoreApplicationSettings()

    varScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    varEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    varCalculation = Application.Calculation

End Sub

Public Sub DisableApplicationSettings()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub

Public Sub RestoreApplicationSettings()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = varScreenUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = varEnableEvents
    Application.Calculation = varCalculation

End Sub
```

Which will return the settings to whatever they were before your sub runs. But, if you really want to do it properly, [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/vba-class-to-persist-and-restore-excel-application-properties) is a much better implementation.

---

And now, in rough order of when I encounter things in your code, these are my thoughts:

---

**Your interruption check could be a lot better**

> ```
> If Int(i / 1000) = i / 1000 Then
>     Debug.Print i
> Else
>     If Int(i / 100) = i / 100 Then
>         DoEvents
>     Else
>     End If
> End If
> ```

Personally, I prefer `Mod()` as in `If i Mod 100 = 0 Then ...`

Also, did you intend for `i` to call `DoEvents` every 100 iterations **except** for every 1000th iteration?

If not, it should be:

```
If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
    DoEvents

    If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print i
End If
```

On this note `i` is not a very useful thing to `Debug.print`. If somebody else runs your program (or if you have more than one thing to print to the immediate window) then it's going to be very difficult to figure out what is going on.

I recommend something like: `Debug.Print "[Name of procedure / loop / some other descriptor] - Iteration Counter: " & i`

Since it's in a `For` Loop, you already know how many iterations it should run for, so you should probably include that as well.

This:

> ```
> For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
>     Results(i) = Dic.Items(i)
>     If Int(i / 1000) = i / 1000 Then
>         Debug.Print i
>     Else
>         If Int(i / 100) = i / 100 Then
>             DoEvents
>         Else
>         End If
>     End If
> Next i
> ```

Then Becomes:

```
For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
    Results(i) = Dic.Items(i)


    If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
        DoEvents

        If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print "Copy Dic to Results Array - Iteration Counter: " & i & " / " & Dic.Count - 1
    End If
Next i
```

And rather than seeing this in your immediate window:

> 1000
>   2000
>   3000
>   4000

You'll see

> Copy Dic to Results Array - Iteration Counter: 1000 / 4192
>   Copy Dic to Results Array - Iteration Counter: 2000 / 4192
>   Copy Dic to Results Array - Iteration Counter: 3000 / 4192
>   Copy Dic to Results Array - Iteration Counter: 4000 / 4192

Much more useful.

---

**Be Explicit**

`Sub` is not `Sub` it is actually (implicitly) `Public Sub`
Same with `Function` --> `Public Function`
And `Dim A` --> `Dim A As Variant`

Methods should be `Public` or `Private`
Variables should have an explicit type (even if that type is intended to be `Variant`).

You do at least appear to be declaring your variables, so +1 for that.

---

**Don't abuse the `_` operator.**

> ```
> Dim A() As String, _  
>     wb As Workbook, _  
>     wS As Worksheet, _  
>     Dic As Scripting.Dictionary, _  
>     DicItm As Variant, _  
>     NbMaxWords As Integer, _  
>     TpStr As String, _  
>     Results() As Variant, _  
>     DicItm2 As Object, _  
>     R(), _  
>     iA As Long, _  
>     i As Long, _  
>     j As Long, _  
>     k As Long, _  
>     c As Range
> ```

Why do you want all these declarations on the same line?
Just declare them separately like so:

```
Dim A() As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Dic As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim DicItm As Variant

Dim NBMaxWords as Integer
```

etc.

Now, you don't have to spend precious development time fiddling around with alignments and the inevitable missing / mis-typed `_`s that will crop up.

---

**Good naming is really, really important**

To quote developers far more experienced than I:

> "There are only three hard things in computer science:
>   cache invalidation, off-by-one errors and naming things."

Good names should be **Clear, Concise and Unambiguous**.
Variables should sound like **what they are**.

`ArrayToAnalyse` is a good name. It is "the array this function needs to analyse". Awesome.

`TpStr` is not. I haven't got the faintest idea what this thing is or what it's meant to represent. I just spent a minute looking for it in your code to try and figure it out and I've **still** got no idea what it really is, except that it invariably gets "cleaned" and then added to your dictionary.

`A()` and `R()` are particularly bad. I know they're arrays (due to their declaration) but I've got no idea what they're meant to be used for.

When I see `A = Split(ArrayToAnalyse(iA, ColumnToAnalyse), " ")` in your code, how am I meant to know that it should be `A` and not `R`?

Whereas if `A` was called, say, `splitString` and `R` was called `resultsStorage` then it's much easier to spot errors. (I don't actually know what R should be called, your names make it difficult to figure out what's actually going on and why).

Also,

[Standard VBA Naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables, and `PascalCase` only for sub/function names and Module/Global Variables. This allows you to tell at a glance if the variable you're looking at is local to your procedure, or coming from somewhere else.

So:

```
Dim localScope as Variant

Private ModuleScope as Variant
Public GlobalScope as Variant

Public/Private Const CONSTANT_VALUE as String = "This value never changes"

Public Sub DoThisThing (ByRef firstParameter as Variant)
```

following standard conventions is good because it allows other developers to easily read and understand your code.

---

Comment: @Raystafarian : Just stumble upon on that issue too, but no, it does need to `a mod b` to make it work!

@Zak : Thx for the quick answer, I totally forgot to include the `Application. ...` even though I knew them. 

Good improvement for the interruption check (edit the `mod` though) and thx for the Standard VBA Naming conventions, that'll help to keep this tighter! 

About the `_` for declarations, could it impact code efficiency? Because, I know it is not super practical to type but I find this easier to read!

Comment: @R3uK I advise you to drop that habit. a) because standard practice is to `Dim` things on separate lines and conforming to standard layouts is a really good habit to get into. b) because you shouldn't be declaring all your variables up top like that anyway. You should be declaring them as close to their eventual usage as possible.

Comment: @Raystafarian My bad on `Mod`. Haven't coded that in quite a while. Edited it to the correct usage.

Comment: whoops, forgot the +1